# How to predict which type of optical isomerism

Tags: organic-chemistry, optical-properties

When I learnt about optical activity in school, my teacher told me that there is no way to theoritically predict whether a compound is dextrorotatory or leuvorotatory. How is that possible?

Comment: Hope you make it to OCSC!

Comment: Because it may happen that some compound is dextrorotatory for one color (one wavelength) and levorotatory for another color (another wavelength)

Comment: You can estimate via computational chemistry.

Comment: In terms of why it's hard, consider the amino acids for the biologically prevalent enantiomer. If I told you the specific rotation for one of them, can you tell me the sign of the specific rotation of any other?

Comment: @WilliamR.Ebenezer I thought OCSC term is used in my country only, is it used all across the world? Also have you attended OCSC?

Comment: @Zenix, Nah, I couldn't make it. Didn't score enough. And yes, I believe the term is used worldwide.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who spent time to reply to my question. Thank you William for your wishes. Maurice, I understood your point. I didn't quite understand what Zhe meant in his second comment.

Comment: A more accurate statement might be "not by simple inspection". And there might be a significant margin of error even in the best theory.

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83990/what-is-occuring-on-the-quantum-level-when-a-molecule-rotates-plane-polarized-li/84136#84136