# How does optical activity work?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

I have learnt that chiral molecules are able to show optical activity; that is, they are able to rotate plane polarized light by some angle.

But how does it actually happen? Won't the orientation of the molecule also depend on whether it causes clockwise or anticlockwise rotation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: There are quite a few answers and relevant questions here, such as this one: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/84136/79678. I suggest following the link and exploring related items on the right side.

Comment: Excellent one here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/6277/79678.

Comment: @Draculin https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15503/how-do-optically-active-compounds-rotate-plane-polarized-light?rq=1 This one as well.