Why and how optically active compounds rotate plane polarized light
I know that optically active compounds rotate plane polarized light, but I wanted to know how they do it? Why is that only molecules with chiral carbon atoms are able to rotate plane polarized light, while other symmetric carbon cannot? What has unsymmetricity to do with rotation of light?

See Why do only chiral molecules rotate the plane of polarized light and how do they rotate it?

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15503/373758

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83990/what-is-occuring-on-the-quantum-level-when-a-molecule-rotates-plane-polarized-li
