# How can randomly oriented molecules in a liquid solution create a certain polarization pattern (d or l)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, chirality, optical-properties

How can a large number of moving, randomly-oriented chiral molecules in a watery solution twist light only to the left or only to the right?

Wouldn't a levorotary molecule become dextrorotary if I turned it around?

Comment: Please see here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/6277/79678.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Molecular chirality and optical rotation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/6271/molecular-chirality-and-optical-rotation)

Comment: In that sense, you have to think of it like a screw. A screw has the same twist regardless of how you look at it. That's what we mean by left or right handed.